# Subset pandas data frame based on tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataset like this

```
Firstnames = ['AA','BB','CC','AA','CC']
Lastnames = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'P', 'R']
values = [10, 13, 3, 22, 45]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = list(zip(Firstnames,Lastnames,values)), \
                  columns=['Firstnames','Lastnames','values'])
df

    Firstnames  Lastnames   values
0   AA          P           10
1   BB          Q           13
2   CC          R           3
3   AA          P           22
4   CC          R           45
```

I have an array of tuple like this

```
lst = array([('AA', 'P'), ('BB', 'Q')])
```

I want to subset df, such that `Firstname == 'AA' & Lastnames == 'P'`or `Firstname == 'BB' & Lastnames == 'Q'`

I can do this manually, however my array is quite large and I want to do it programmatically

My expected output will be

```
Firstnames  Lastnames   values
AA          P           10
AA          P           22
BB          Q           13
```

Comment: So if you have 10 tuples in array, you expect 10 dfs?

Comment: no, If I have 10 tuples, all my rows will be from these 10 tuples

Comment: @RafaelC, I have updated my question for your better understanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `agg`+`isin`

Since tuples are hashable, you can use `isin` and compare the *aggregated* values to your `last`. Using `lst` and a list directly instead of `np.array` helps.

```
>>> lst = [('AA', 'P'), 
           ('BB', 'Q')]

>>> mask = df[['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']].agg(tuple, 1).isin(lst)
>>> df[mask]

    Firstnames  Lastnames   values
0   AA          P           10
1   BB          Q           13
3   AA          P           22
```

If you want, you can `sort_values` by the names

```
>>> df[mask].sort_values(by=['Firstnames', 'Lastnames'])

    Firstnames  Lastnames   values
0   AA          P           10
3   AA          P           22
1   BB          Q           13
```

---

#### `pd.concat`

You can also use a *list comprehension* and `pd.concat` for smaller `lst`s

```
>>> pd.concat([df[df.Firstnames.eq(a) & df.Lastnames.eq(b)] for a,b in lst])

    Firstnames  Lastnames   values
0   AA          P           10
3   AA          P           22
1   BB          Q           13
```

---

Timings:

Small `lst`, big `df`

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit mask = df[['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']].agg(tuple, 1).isin(lst); df[mask].sort_values(by=['Firstnames', 'Lastnames'])
942 ms ± 71.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.concat([df[df.Firstnames.eq(a) & df.Lastnames.eq(b)] for a,b in lst])
16.2 ms ± 355 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For big `lst` and small `df`

```
c = list(map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_uppercase)))
lst = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(c, list(string.ascii_uppercase)*26)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Firstnames': c, 'Lastnames': list(string.ascii_uppercase)*26, 'values': 10})

%timeit mask = df[['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']].agg(tuple, 1).isin(lst); df[mask].sort_values(by=['Firstnames', 'Lastnames'])
15.1 ms ± 301 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.concat([df[df.Firstnames.eq(a) & df.Lastnames.eq(b)] for a,b in lst])
781 ms ± 33.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `pd.Index.isin`

Convert selected series into a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) object, then use [`pd.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('AA', 'P'), ('BB', 'Q')]
df_masked = df[df.set_index(['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']).index.isin(lst)]
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
# Python 3.6.5, Pandas v0.23.0

lst = [('AA', 'P'), ('BB', 'Q')]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index()

%timeit df[df.set_index(['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']).index.isin(lst)]  # 23.4 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `numpy` broadcasting here for a performant solution.  On massive DataFrames you may start to see a performance hit, at which point you should use `pd.Index.isin`.  You should avoid casting to a `tuple` and using that type of comparison for all sizes of DataFrames.

***Setup***

```
lst = np.array([('AA', 'P'), ('BB', 'Q')])
```

---

```
idx = (df.values[:, :2] == lst[:, None]).any(axis=(0, -1))
df[idx]
```

```
  Firstnames Lastnames  values
0         AA         P      10
1         BB         Q      13
3         AA         P      22
```

---

***Performance***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index()

In [228]: %timeit df[df.set_index(['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']).index.isin(lst)]
15.5 ms ± 270 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [236]: %%timeit
     ...: mask = df[['Firstnames', 'Lastnames']].agg(tuple, 1).isin(lst)
     ...: df[mask]
     ...:
853 ms ± 22.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [231]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = (df.values[:, :2] == lst[:, None]).any(axis=(0, -1))
     ...: df[idx]
     ...:
11.6 ms ± 264 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```