# slow iterating through multi index pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, vectorization, multi-index

I have a big dataFrame with three indexes

```
df = df.set_index(['i','j','k']
```

I have identified `feasible_i_j` rows meeting a given formula for 'i' and 'j' so that I can filter the `df` with `.loc`

```
rows = df.loc[feasible_i_j[0],feasible_i_j[1],:]
```

now I want to filter the dataFrame also for rows for which also for 'k' returns True from some function `foo`:

```
for feasible_i_j in feasible_i_js: 
    rows = df.loc[feasible_i_j[0],feasible_i_j[1],:]
    for row in range(rows.shape[0]):
        flag = foo(rows.iloc[row])
```

And this is horribly slow and unefficient. I am looking for **a way to speed it up** , specifically since `foo` can be vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804320/subset-pandas-data-frame-based-on-tuple) post (you may want to try the other ones to see which one works faster for you)

```py
df= pandas.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'A':['A','B','C']})
ls=[('a','A'),('b','B')]
print(df)
rows = pandas.concat([df[df.a.eq(x) & df.A.eq(y)] for x,y in ls])
```

For the `foo()` function, if you can vectorize it I guess you can just call it like that : 
`df = foo(df)` or `df['XXX'] = foo(df['XXX'])`
If not you can do a `df=df.apply(lambda row: foo(row),axis=1)`

Comment: thanks, it helped, however my triple indexes seems to be making more problems rather than helping ;)