# Pick unique rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

Original:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        "color": ["red","blue","green","yellow","red","blue","green","yellow","red","blue","green","yellow","red","blue","green","yellow"]
    }
)
```

| ID | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | green |
| 1 | yellow |
| 2 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 2 | green |
| 2 | yellow |
| 3 | red |
| 3 | blue |
| 3 | green |
| 3 | yellow |
| 4 | red |
| 4 | blue |
| 4 | green |
| 4 | yellow |

I want to remove duplicates / pick unique rows in a specific manner so that result will look like this...

| ID | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 3 | green |
| 4 | yellow |

Tried to remove duplicates by either "ID" or "color" but the other column always gets single value repeated 4 times. Parameter `keep` is not helping (just reverses the result)

Remove duplicates by ID (same color):
`df.drop_duplicates("ID")`

| ID | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | red |
| 3 | red |
| 4 | red |

Remove duplicates by color (same ID):
`df.drop_duplicates("color")`

| ID | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | green |
| 1 | yellow |

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:
Just came up with this clumsy solution ...

```
series = []
for i, (_, sub) in enumerate(df.groupby("ID")):
    series.append(sub.iloc[i])

out = pandas.concat(series, axis=1).transpose().reset_index(drop=True)
```

... but Mark`s answer is much simpler

Thanks!

EDIT 2:
Another solution that fits me best
(based on this topic: [Subset pandas data frame based on tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804320/subset-pandas-data-frame-based-on-tuple))
I know that zip will pack all values together until the shortest one is exhausted but this is OK since in my scenario length of "ID" and "color" stays always equal

```
zipped = zip(df["ID"].unique(), df["color"].unique())
mask = df[["ID", "color"]].agg(tuple, 1).isin(zipped)

df[mask]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the specific filtering manner a bit more? What is the expected logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're not actually looking for the unique rows:

```
# get unique rows of ID and color
df.drop_duplicates()

    ID   color
0    1     red
1    1    blue
2    1   green
3    1  yellow
4    2     red
5    2    blue
6    2   green
7    2  yellow
8    3     red
9    3    blue
10   3   green
11   3  yellow
12   4     red
13   4    blue
14   4   green
15   4  yellow
```

Those *are* the unique rows of the dataframe. The thing you want is the unique values of the two columns *joined as a new dataframe*:

```
# get unique values of ID
ids = df.ID.unique() # array(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'], dtype=object)

# get unique values of color
colors = df.color.unique() # array([1, 2, 3, 4])


new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID": ids, "color": colors}
)

   ID   color
0   1     red
1   2    blue
2   3   green
3   4  yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Will the number of unique values for ID and color always be the same?

If so, you can use Mark's solution, otherwise you may not be able to organize them into a Dataframe, try to store them in multiple arrays.

```
# Just leave them alone
ids = df.ID.unique()
colors = df.color.unique()
```

Comment: this is the true correct answer- my answer isn't robust to differing numbers of ids and colours, but idk ‍♂️

Comment: "Will the number of unique values for ID and color always be the same?" Yes.